# how to attach javadocs from maven repositories to your own javadocs

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, javadoc

I am working on maven based spring boot project. Which is using dependencies like EurekaClient Spring Security etc.

I want javadocs to include javadocs for annotations from their respective jars used in project. I also tried @see tag to attach their docs, but this doesn't make classes clickable outside the project.

I also downloaded the source and javadocs of the jar files in maven dependencies. But this doesn't seem to work.

In eclipse Project-> Generate Javadocs wizard I have selected desired jar files to link, however either they doesn't attach or throw exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Extern.readPackageListFromURL(Extern.java:235)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Extern.link(Extern.java:180)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:528)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.Configuration.setOptions(Configuration.java:554)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:134)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:80)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:310)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:189)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:366)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:219)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:205)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:64)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```